# How to install gearman extension in php7 running on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php-7, ubuntu-18.04, gearman

I am currently required to setup the new server running php7.2 and the server will have many background process for sending emails to customer. the recommendation I got was to use Gearman Job Server.
I have been searching but seems to have only post about gearman-job-server with php5 and below.

Answer (score 5):

The process of installing Gearman Job Server with php7 will be covered in like 4 steps

Install and update the Gearman PPA 
`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gearman-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update`

Install Gearman Job Server and some other required components and tools 
`sudo apt-get install gearman-job-server libgearman-dev php7.0-dev php-pear wget unzip re2c
sudo apt-get upgrade`

Download, compile the gearman pecl module and add to php.ini 
`cd /tmp/
sudo wget https://github.com/wcgallego/pecl-gearman/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd pecl-gearman-master
sudo phpize
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
echo "extension=gearman.so" | sudo tee /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/gearman.ini
sudo phpenmod -v ALL -s ALL gearman`

Restart webserver or PHP FPM 
`sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
sudo service apache2 restart`

If you are running a different version of PHP make sure you make the appropriate changes to the commands or directories mentioned above. ie “/etc/php/7.0/” to “/etc/php/7.1/” etc.

Thanks to techearl.com for their tutorial which can be found 
[Here](https://techearl.com/php/installing-gearman-module-for-php7-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Ruberandinda Patience is correct and will work but since the gearman pecl module is [packaged for Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php/php-gearman) there is a much simpler way to achieve the same thing:

```
apt install gearman-job-server php-gearman
```