# Cannot run Gearman worker - undefined symbol: ZVAL_NEW_ARR

Tags: php, gearman

I have installed Gearman on my system and when I run `php --info | grep gearman` I've got

```
php --info | grep gearman
gearman
gearman support => enabled
libgearman version => 1.1.19.1+ds
```

Also, I have added in php.ini - `extension=/usr/lib/php/20210902/gearman.so`

`lsof -i tcp:4730` shows that it is running

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gearmand 297767 root   10u  IPv4 1211167      0t0  TCP localhost:4730 (LISTEN)
```

When I try to run a worker I've got:

```
php: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/php/20210902/gearman.so: undefined symbol: ZVAL_NEW_ARR
```

Workers/clients are the basic ones from the Gearman page. Worker:

```
<?php
$worker= new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();
$worker->addFunction("reverse", "my_reverse_function");
while ($worker->work());

function my_reverse_function($job)
{
  return strrev($job->workload());
}
?>
```

Client

```
<?php
$client= new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();
print $client->do("reverse", "Hello World!");
?>
```

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Your extension is wrong. Are you sure it's for correct PHP version?

Comment: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/php-gearman-undefined-symbol-zend_new_interned_string-in-unknown-on-line-0-a-941003/

Comment: I believe. I mean I have downloaded latest version of gearman and installed it.

Comment: But is your PHP version compatible with that extension? You can't install PHP8 extension for PHP5 and expect it to work

Comment: Did you resolve this? As i am having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was because the latest release of Gearman doesn't support php8.1 (https://github.com/php/pecl-networking-gearman/commit/7da13e4babc17067b2b45d6b37041c3c8ed91637).

I used the build instructions from [How to install gearman extension in php7 running on ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57783412/how-to-install-gearman-extension-in-php7-running-on-ubuntu-18-04) but cloned the latest commit from their git repo instead of using the downloadable package and that worked for me.

So for me running on centos7 with php8.1 from remi's repo I had...

```
git clone https://github.com/php/pecl-networking-gearman.git
cd pecl-networking-gearman
/opt/remi/php81/root/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/remi/php81/root/bin/php-config
make
make install
echo "extension=gearman.so" | tee /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-gearman.ini
```

Comment: Using my repo, you don't have to buid from sources. Gearman, like most extensions is available as RPM ;)
See  the list https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status